# What commands can be used to get every player down to half a heart?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I don't know what commands to use to get every player down to half a heart in *Minecraft: Education Edition*.

Answer (score 2):

Just [poison](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Poison) everyone.

```
effect give @a minecraft:Poison 3600 5
```

Comment: Why the spolier markup?

Comment: @pppery Low effort question. Besides, it's doable without commands (a method for someone who hasn't touched commands before) :P